# What are the four cheeses generally used in"four-cheese" pizzas?

Tags: cheese, pizza

In common consumer pizza, microwave and bake-at-home pizzas are often advertised as **four-cheese pizzas.** What are these four cheeses, traditionally? Do different brands use different mixes, or does everyone stay about the same? How are these cheeses traditionally mixed, in what fashion?

Comment: What do you mean by "traditionally"? Whose tradition?

Comment: Excellent point— Any commercial bake-at-home pizza that claims to be "four-cheese." I was asking if there was a tradition at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They all seem to use different cheeses depending on the brand.

- The most consistent cheese is definitely mozzarella, which makes sense as it's the default cheese on most pizzas.
- Second to that is some sort of hard grating cheese like Parmesan or Asiago... which also makes sense as it's a traditional pizza condiment.
- Other Italian cheeses also seem popular like fontina and provolone
- But non-Italian cheeses like cheddar certainly show up.

Below are some examples. I don't recommend any of these products, they just came up in web searches and specifically describe which four cheeses they use.

Amy's uses: Fontina, provolone, Parmesan, mozzarella:

[image: Amy's Pizza]

Frontera uses: Mozzarella, white cheddar, smoked provolone, asiago.

[image: Frontera Pizza]

California Pizza Kitchen uses: Mozzarella (apparently more than one kind), fontina, gouda

[image: California Pizza Kitchen]

Lean Cuisine uses: low fat mozzarella, Parmesan, asiago, romano

[image: Lean Cuisine Pizza]

Comment: The Gouda on the California Pizza is intriguing.

Answer (score 4):

As others have noted, there is no standard.

Pizza's nominally Italian it would make sense to stick to the Italian cheeses or at least start with them.  And there's no point if you cannot taste the distinction between them, so why not go for cheeses that have distinct personality.  Finally, while you can mix them evenly, also consider spreading them in clumps so that each bite has a bit different flavor.

As an example, one could use mozzarella for the base, then scatter chunks of gorgonzola, tallegio, and smoked provolone.  You can use big chunks--the size of a postage stamp and maybe 1/3 as thick--because these cheese all melt well.

If the cheeses are of equal character your starting point could be to use about equal amounts of these four by weight.  For example, 125g of each of the above four would suffice for an entire 11x14", 27x35cm thin pizza (the pizza size pictured, though its only half a 4-cheese).  Alternatively you could skip one of these soft cheeses and instead just cover the thing with a grated hard cheese, parmesan (a bit sour) or pecorino romano (tangy).

Moving a bit further beyond your question, when making a 4-cheese sauce for pasta one example formula would be 2 parts gorgonzola, 1 part tallegio, 1 part parmesan, and 1 part ricotta.  100g total cheese melted in 200g cream would be two servings or so.

[image: raw pizza]

Comment: Hello Swiss Frank, and welcome! I know that our site can be a little confusing to new users, but we have a pretty strong rule here that we don't answer questions of the "what should I put on my pizza" type, because they produce unredable long lists of personal favorites. After you went to the trouble of posting an answer, We can let your suggestions pass as an example illustrating the "there is no standard" part, but I removed the "I think you wanted to know what to put on your pizza" sentence, because it steers the question (and possibly the next person who answers) in the wrong direction.

Comment: yes first-time poster and apologies.  I edited to make it  "rules of thumb" instead of "what I'd do."

Comment: @SwissFrank that aside, the pizza looks really good even without the sauce.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to edit your answer. We look forward to more contributions from you!